# For loop not running through the whole range, it only deletes half the values

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Dim rcell As Range, k As Range
Dim y As Long
Dim lastrow As String
Sheets("Shipment").Activate
lastrow = Sheets("Shipment").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Past Data").Activate 
y = Sheets("Past Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Sheets("Shipment").Activate 
Set k = ActiveSheet.Range("D3:D" & lastrow) 
For Each rcell In k

If rcell.Value = "REQ" Then
rcell.EntireRow.Delete

ElseIf rcell = "Completed" Then

rcell.EntireRow.Copy 
Sheets("Past Data").Range("A" & y).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 
y = y + 1

End If

Next rcell
```

The problem I am facing is that the code goes through the range but deletes only half the values and leaves the rest. Absolutely no idea why it does that. I have tried different things, tried using `For i = 3 to lastrow` and changed the code. Still, it does it. For example: if there are 109 values it deletes leaves 55, then i run it again it leaves 28. I don't understand why doesn't it delete all in one go.
Help is appreciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: Does the cell value match the "REQ" condition?

Comment: yup it does meet the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because, when deleting the current row, the next row becomes current row after deletion. The macro doesn't know this, however, and jumps one row down.

For example:

```
Rows    Status  
A       Current row
B       Next row
C       Next-next row
```

When the macro deletes row A, you expect it to go on to delete row B. But what really happens, is:

1. Row A is deleted.
2. Row B becomes current row when row A is deleted.
3. The macro jumps to the next row.
4. Meaning macro is now positioned on row C, leaving row B undeleted.

Example fix:

```
For i = 100 To 1 Step -1
    ' Some code
Next i
```

This code will start at the bottom and work its way upwards, eliminating the problem detailed above. The loop means: "start at i = 100, put i = i - 1 every step, until i = 1".

Comment: my friend. You are a genius. Thanks a lot, it works perfectly! something new i have learnt today. I had no idea such a thing could be the problem.